# ¿Cómo hago para relacionar una ForeignKey de un models a la view o base de datos en Django?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, django, django-models, django-views

Realicé un models con relaciones de tablas utilizando ForeignKeys. Realicé su respectivos forms y views. Solo que ahora no se cargan los datos ingresados a la base de datos de esa ForeignKey, en este caso es num_dni.

Adjunto mi código:

Models:

```
class Dueno(models.Model):
    localidad = models.CharField('Localidad', max_length=150, null=True)

class Persona(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre/s', max_length=150)
    apellido = models.CharField('Apellido/s', max_length=150)
    direccion = models.CharField('Dirección', max_length=150)
    telefono = models.IntegerField('Teléfono')
    num_dni = models.ForeignKey(Dueno, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Forms:

```
class Dueno_Paciente(forms.Form):
    nombre = forms.CharField(label='Nombre', max_length=150)
    apellido = forms.CharField(label='Apellido', max_length=150)
    telefono = forms.IntegerField(label='Teléfono')
    direccion = forms.CharField(label='Dirección', max_length=150)
    dni = forms.CharField(label='DNI')
```

Views:

```
def paciente_form(request, template_name='entidad/f_paciente.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        f_dueno = Persona()
        f_dueno.nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
        f_dueno.apellido = request.POST.get('apellido')
        f_dueno.telefono = request.POST.get('telefono')
        f_dueno.direccion = request.POST.get('direccion')
        f_dueno.num_dni = request.POST.get('num_dni')
        f_dueno.save()

        return HttpResponse('Exito!')
    else:
        f_dueno = Dueno_Paciente()

    # este dato que contiene form es el form que se muestra en el html
    dato = {
        'f_dueno': f_dueno
    }
    return render(request, template_name, dato)
```

Necesito saber cómo cargar los datos de una ForeignKey a la base de datos utilizando Django. Intenté con ejemplos como ModelsChoiceFields pero no es lo que busco o necesito ya que lo que hace es desplegarme un selector pero no me permite ingresar nada.